# Multiple controllers?

Tags: php, url-routing

I am using a MVC Framework for my PHP projects and how it works is as follows:
We have the a root that's like http://localhost/myproject.

And it accepts an url like this: http://localhost/myproject/example-controller/example-function/params

So what it does is it goes to the example-controller and executes the function example-function where we have the possibility to add parameters like http://localhost/myproject/example-controller/example-function/1/2/3

So I have a dashboard where I want to be able to apply crud functionality to users and articles so the url becomes as follows: 
http://localhost/myproject/dashboard/users, which means that it will execute the function users but let's say I want to create a new user the link then becomes dashboard/users/create but it will see create as a parameter and not as an actual function that needs to be executed.. so I understand I would have to make a UserController and a ArticleController but that means the link will become user/create or article/create in which case it doesn't use the DashboardController anymore.

If anyone understood what I tried to describe could someone come up with a possible explanation on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you tell us which MVC Framework you're using?

Comment: MVC frameworks tend to let you alter the router to  manually map routes to functions in a controller. For example with Laravel: `Route::get('/dashboard/users/create', 'DashboardController@createuser');` would map it to the createuser function on DashboardController

Comment: Back in the day before I used a router i would break up the url so it would look like `/controller/method/action/subaction/subaction_id` and so on... fyi dashboard should not be in the user controller so `/user/create` or `/user/edit/123` fits in then. Also doing rest and utilising http methods can again remove the need for create, update, delete actions in the url.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a solution to my problem and rewrote the whole `splitUrl()` function so it now accepts what I need.

```
function splitUrl() 
{
    if (isset($_GET['url'])) {        
        require(ROOT. 'core/routes.php');

    $tmp_url = trim($_GET['url'], "/");
    $tmp_url = filter_var($tmp_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    $tmp_url = explode("/", $tmp_url);
    $param = ['params' => [], 'found' => false];
    foreach ($routes as $route => $value) {
        //echo("We iterate over a new route called <strong>". $route. "</strong><br>");
        $tmp_route = explode("/", $route);

        // Variables for the length of the arrays;
        $route_count = count($tmp_route);
        $url_count = count($tmp_url);

        //echo("The route count = <strong>". $route_count . "</strong> and the url count = <strong>". $url_count. "</strong><br>");

        // Check if the length of the route in our acceptable routes array is equal to the length of the url. 
         if ($route_count == $url_count) {
             $indexCount = null;
             for ($i = 0; $i < $route_count; $i++) { 
                 if ($tmp_route[$i] == '{param}') {
                     $indexCount = $i;
                     //echo("A parameter has been found at index <strong>" . $indexCount . "</strong><br>");
                     break;
                 }
             }

             if ($indexCount == null) {
                 $indexCount = count($tmp_route); 
                //echo("A parameter has NOT been found so the index has been set to <strong>". $indexCount. "</strong><br>");
             }

            $doContinue = false;
             for ($i = 0; $i < $indexCount; $i++) { 
                 //echo("We are comparing value <strong>". $tmp_route[$i] . "</strong> to <strong>". $tmp_url[$i] ."</strong><br>"); 

                 if ($tmp_route[$i] == $tmp_url[$i]) {
                     //echo("Value <strong>". $tmp_route[$i] ."</strong> appears to be valid<br>");
                     continue;
                 } else {
                     //echo("Value <strong>". $tmp_route[$i] ."</strong> appears to be invalid<br><hr>");
                     $doContinue = true;
                     break;
                 }
             }

             if ($doContinue) continue;

             $count = 0;
             for ($i = 0; $i < $route_count; $i++) { 
                 if ($tmp_route[$i] == $tmp_url[$count]) {
                     $count++;
                    continue;
                 } else {
                     array_push($param['params'], $tmp_url[$count]);
                    $count++;
                 }
             }
        } else {
            // This means the route that we are iterating over right now can not possibly be the one we are looking for as the length is not equal to the length of the url.
            continue;
        }

        $param['controller'] = explode("@", $value)[0];
        $param['action'] = explode("@", $value)[1];

        return $param;
     }
}
```

Comment: answers which are blob of code w/o any explanation what you exactly did are pretty useless for anyone looking for solution to similar problem.